# How does dynamic recompilation handle instruction-pointer checks in software virtualization?

Tags: compilation, x86, virtualbox, virtualization, x86-emulation

*(This question isn't intended to be specific to VirtualBox or x86 per se, but since they're the best examples I'm aware of, I'll be referencing them and asking how VBox handles some scenarios. If you're aware of other solutions that aren't used by VBox, do consider mentioning them as well.)*

---

I've read [how VirtualBox does software virtualization](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#idm9822), and I don't understand the following.

> Before executing ring 0 code, CSAM *[Code Scanning and Analysis Manager]* scans it recursively to discover problematic instructions. PATM *[Patch Manager]* then performs in-situ patching, i.e. it replaces the instruction with a jump to hypervisor memory where an integrated code generator has placed a more suitable implementation. In reality, this is a very complex task as there are lots of odd situations to be discovered and handled correctly. So, with its current complexity, one could argue that PATM is an advanced in-situ recompiler.

Consider the following sample instruction sequence in ring-0 code:

```
    call foo

foo:
    mov EAX, 1234
    mov EDX, [ESP]
    cmp EDX, EAX
    jne bar
    call do_something_special_if_return_address_was_1234
bar:
    ...
```

The callee here is testing to see if the return address to the caller is `1234`, and if it is, it does something special. Clearly patching will change the return address, so we need to be able to handle it.

VirtualBox's documentation says it discovers "problematic" instructions and patches them in-place, but I don't really understand how this can work, for 2 reasons:

1. It appears that *any instruction* that exposes the instruction pointer is "problematic", of which `call` is probably the most common (and extremely so). Does this mean VirtualBox must analyze, and potentially patch, *every* `call` instruction it sees in ring 0? Doesn't this make performance drop off a cliff? How do they handle this with high performance? (The cases they mention in their documentation are quite obscure, so I'm confused why they didn't mention such a common instruction if it occurs. And if it isn't a problem, I don't understand why.)
2. If the instruction stream happens to be modified (e.g. dynamically loading/unloading kernel modules), VirtualBox must dynamically detect this and garbage-collect unreachable recompiled instructions. Otherwise, it will have a memory leak. But this means *every* `mov` instruction (and `push` instruction, and everything else that writes to memory) will now have to be analyzed and potentially patched, possibly repeatedly, because it may be modifying code that was patched. This would seem to essentially degenerate *all* guest ring-0 code into near-full software emulation (since the target of a move is not known during recompilation), which would make the virtualization cost *skyrocket*, and yet this is not the impression I get from reading the documentation. Is this not a problem? How is this handled efficiently?

Please note that I am ***not*** asking about hardware-assisted virtualization like Intel VT or AMD-V and I am *not* interested in reading about those. I'm well aware that they avoid these problems altogether, but my question is about pure software virtualization.

Comment: An interesting & well-posed question! I don't know nearly enough about this to post an answer, but I do know that VirtualBox uses QEMU as the basis for its dynamic recompiler, which is presumably involved in this type of analysis and virtualization. Its performance has gotten pretty good over the years, so this probably isn't the perf cliff you think it is. It's got to parse the code anyway to replace privileged insns with context switches, so some perf degradation is inevitable. All patching is done live in RAM, though, so I don't see how memory leaks would be a problem.

Comment: Very interesting question. I guess one possibility is that such checks may simply fail in the virtualized environment. You can only rely on a specific value anyway when you are sure the loader doesn't relocate your binary (which is true, AFAIK, for the initial executable on Linux, but not shared libraries). Another possibility is that the re-writing tries to leave all the `call` instructions in their original locations, and then re-writes around them as necessary, e.g, by `jmp` out to the new code, and then `jmp` back prior to a call, or with a fake-call: `push 0x1234; jmp`.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks! The reason memory leaks would be a problem is that when you recompile code you have to put it somewhere else (the original spot doesn't have room) and that means when the original code goes away the recompiled code needs to go away too, otherwise you'll run out of RAM.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yeah I was wondering if such checks might fail too, but that seems unlikely since I don't really get that impression from VirtualBox or QEMU's documentation. Though it's pretty easy to test... just haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: Yeah, I found that it does get the right values, and it does it by emulating the stack and then removing the various `call` and `ret` instructions and replacing them with internal QEMU generated code that jumps to the right place. In your example above, it means that `call foo` is no longer a `call` but a bunch of code that sets up the emulated stack to contain `0x1234` (if that was the return for `call foo`) and then the code at `foo` will examine this emulated stack and see the right value. Details in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least for `QEMU`, it seems like the answer is that even in the translated code, there is a separate *emulated* "stack" that is set up with the same values as the code would have when running natively, and this "stack" is the one read by the emulated code, which sees the same values as if it were running natively.

This means that emulated code can't be translated to use `call`, `ret`, or any other stack-using instructions directly, since those would not use the emulated stack. Therefore, those calls are replaced by jumps to various bits of thunk code that does the right thing in terms of calling the equivalent translated code.

## Details for QEMU

The OP's (reasonable) assumption seems to be that `call` and `ret` instructions would appear in the translated binary, and the stack would reflect the addresses of the dynamically translated code. What actually happens (in QEMU) is that the `call` and `ret` instructions are removed and replaced with control flow that doesn't use the stack, and values on the stack are set to have the same values as they would in native code.

That is, the OP's mental model is that the result of the code translation is somewhat like the native code, with some patches and modifications. At least in the case of QEMU, that's not really the case—every basic block is heavily translated via the [Tiny Code Generator (TCG)](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/TCG), first to an intermediate representation and then to the target architecture (even if the source and destination archs are the same, as in my case). [This deck](https://www.slideshare.net/RampantJeff/qemu-binary-translation) has a good overview of a lot of the technical details, including an overview of TCG as shown below.

[image: Diagram of TCG Flow]

The resulting code is usually nothing like the input code, and typically increases in size by about 3 times. Registers are often used fairly sparingly and you often see back-to-back redundant sequences. Particularly relevant to this question, is that essentially all control flow instructions are quite differently, so `ret` and `call` instructions in the native code pretty much never translate into plain `call` or `ret` in the translated code.

An example: First, some C code with a `return_address()` call that simply returns the return address, and a `main()` that prints this function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__ ((noinline)) void* return_address() {
    // stuff here?
    return __builtin_return_address(0);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *a = return_address();
    printf("%p\n", a);
}
```

The `noinline` here is important since otherwise `gcc` just may just inline the function and hardcode the address directly into the assembly without making a `call` or accessing the stack at all!

With `gcc -g -O1 -march=native` this compiles to:

```
0000000000400546 <return_address>:
  400546:       48 8b 04 24             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp]
  40054a:       c3                      ret    

000000000040054b <main>:
  40054b:       48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  40054f:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  400554:       e8 ed ff ff ff          call   400546 <return_address>
  400559:       48 89 c2                mov    rdx,rax
  40055c:       be 04 06 40 00          mov    esi,0x400604
  400561:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  400566:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  40056b:       e8 c0 fe ff ff          call   400430 <__printf_chk@plt>
  400570:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  400575:       48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  400579:       c3                      ret
```

Note that `return_address()` returns `[rsp]` just like the OP's example. The `main()` function sticks it in `rdx`, where `printf` will read it from.

We expect the caller's return address as seen by `return_address` to be the instruction following the call, `0x400559`:

```
  400554:       e8 ed ff ff ff          call   400546 <return_address>
  400559:       48 89 c2                mov    rdx,rax
```

... and indeed that's what we see when we run it natively:

```
person@host:~/dev/test-c$ ./qemu-test 
0x400559
```

Lets try it in QEMU:

```
person@host:~/dev/test-c$ qemu-x86_64 ./qemu-test
0x400559
```

It works! Note that QEMU is by default translating all code and putting it far away from the usual native location (as we will see shortly), so we don't need any special instructions to trigger translation.

How does that work under the covers? We can use the `-d in_asm,out_asm` option with QEMU to see what it is making of this code.

First, the code leading up to the call (the `IN` portion is the native code, and the `OUT` is what QEMU translates it to—sorry for AT&T syntax, I can't figure out how to [change that in QEMU](https://superuser.com/questions/1233450/can-qemu-be-made-to-output-its-assembly-in-intel-syntax)):

```
IN: main
0x000000000040054b:  sub    $0x8,%rsp
0x000000000040054f:  mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400554:  callq  0x400546

OUT: [size=123]
0x557c9cf33a40:  mov    -0x8(%r14),%ebp
0x557c9cf33a44:  test   %ebp,%ebp
0x557c9cf33a46:  jne    0x557c9cf33aac
0x557c9cf33a4c:  mov    0x20(%r14),%rbp
0x557c9cf33a50:  sub    $0x8,%rbp
0x557c9cf33a54:  mov    %rbp,0x20(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a58:  mov    $0x8,%ebx
0x557c9cf33a5d:  mov    %rbx,0x98(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a64:  mov    %rbp,0x90(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a6b:  xor    %ebx,%ebx
0x557c9cf33a6d:  mov    %rbx,(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a70:  sub    $0x8,%rbp
0x557c9cf33a74:  mov    $0x400559,%ebx
0x557c9cf33a79:  mov    %rbx,0x0(%rbp)
0x557c9cf33a7d:  mov    %rbp,0x20(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a81:  mov    $0x11,%ebp
0x557c9cf33a86:  mov    %ebp,0xa8(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a8d:  jmpq   0x557c9cf33a92
0x557c9cf33a92:  movq   $0x400546,0x80(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a9d:  mov    $0x7f177ad8a690,%rax
0x557c9cf33aa7:  jmpq   0x557c9cef8196
0x557c9cf33aac:  mov    $0x7f177ad8a693,%rax
0x557c9cf33ab6:  jmpq   0x557c9cef8196
```

A key part is here:

```
0x557c9cf33a74:  mov    $0x400559,%ebx
0x557c9cf33a79:  mov    %rbx,0x0(%rbp)
```

You can see that it is actually manually putting the return address *from the native code* onto the "stack" (which seems generally to be accessed with `rbp`). Following that, note that there is no `call` instruction to `return_address`. Rather, we have:

```
0x557c9cf33a92:  movq   $0x400546,0x80(%r14)
0x557c9cf33a9d:  mov    $0x7f177ad8a690,%rax
0x557c9cf33aa7:  jmpq   0x557c9cef8196
```

In most of the code, `r14` seems to be a pointer to some internal QEMU data structure (i.e., not used to hold values from the emulated program). The above shoves `0x400546` (which is the address of the `return_address` function *in native code*) into a field of the structure pointed to by `r14`, sticks `0x7f177ad8a690` in `rax`, and jumps to `0x557c9cef8196`. This last address appears all over the place in the generated code (but its definition does not) and seems to be some kind of internal dispatch or thunk method. Presumably, it uses either the native address or, more likely, the mystery value shoved in `rax` to dispatch to the translated `return_address` method, which looks like this:

```
----------------
IN: return_address
0x0000000000400546:  mov    (%rsp),%rax
0x000000000040054a:  retq   

OUT: [size=64]
0x55c131ef9ad0:  mov    -0x8(%r14),%ebp
0x55c131ef9ad4:  test   %ebp,%ebp
0x55c131ef9ad6:  jne    0x55c131ef9b01
0x55c131ef9adc:  mov    0x20(%r14),%rbp
0x55c131ef9ae0:  mov    0x0(%rbp),%rbx
0x55c131ef9ae4:  mov    %rbx,(%r14)
0x55c131ef9ae7:  mov    0x0(%rbp),%rbx
0x55c131ef9aeb:  add    $0x8,%rbp
0x55c131ef9aef:  mov    %rbp,0x20(%r14)
0x55c131ef9af3:  mov    %rbx,0x80(%r14)
0x55c131ef9afa:  xor    %eax,%eax
0x55c131ef9afc:  jmpq   0x55c131ebe196
0x55c131ef9b01:  mov    $0x7f9ba51f7713,%rax
0x55c131ef9b0b:  jmpq   0x55c131ebe196
```

The first bit of code seems to set up the user "stack" in `ebp` (getting it from `r14 + 0x20`, which is probably the emulated machine state structure) and ultimately reads from the "stack" (the line `mov  0x0(%rbp),%rbx`) and stores that away into the area pointed to by `r14` (`mov  %rbx,0x80(%r14)`).

Finally, it gets to `jmpq  0x55c131ebe196`, which transfers to the QEMU epilogue routine:

```
0x55c131ebe196:  add    $0x488,%rsp
0x55c131ebe19d:  pop    %r15
0x55c131ebe19f:  pop    %r14
0x55c131ebe1a1:  pop    %r13
0x55c131ebe1a3:  pop    %r12
0x55c131ebe1a5:  pop    %rbx
0x55c131ebe1a6:  pop    %rbp
0x55c131ebe1a7:  retq
```

Note that I use the word "stack" in quotes above. This is because this "stack" is the *emulation* of the stack as seen by the emulated program, not the true stack pointed to by `rsp`. The true stack pointed to by `rsp` is controlled by QEMU to implement the emulated control flow, and the emulated code doesn't access it directly.

### Some Things Can Change

We see above that "stack" *contents* as seen by the emulated process are the same under QEMU, but details of the stack do change. For example, the *address* of the stack looks different under emulation than natively (i.e., the *value* of `rsp` rather than the stuff pointed to by `[rsp]`).

This function:

```
__attribute__ ((noinline)) void* return_address() {
    return __builtin_frame_address(0);
}
```

normally returns addresses like `0x7fffad33c100` but returns addresses like `0x40007ffd00` under QEMU. This should not be a problem, though, because no valid program should depend on the exact absolute value of the stack address. Not only is it generally not defined and unpredictable, but on recent operating systems it really is *designed* to be totally unpredictable due to stack [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (Linux and Windows both implement this). The program above returns a different address each time I run it natively (but the same address under QEMU).

### Self Modifying Code

You also mentioned a concern about when the instruction stream is modified, and gave an example of loading a kernel module. First, at least for QEMU, code is only translated "on demand". Functions that could be called, but aren't in some particular run, are never translated (you can try it with a function that is called conditionally depending on `argc`). So in general, loading new code into the kernel, or into a process in user-mode emulation, is handled by the same mechanism: the code will simply be translated the first time it is called.

If the code is actually *self modifying*—i.e., the process writes to its own code—then something has to be done, since without help QEMU would keep using the old translation. So, to detect self-modifying code without penalizing every write to memory, the native code lives in pages with R+X permissions only. The consequence is that a write raises a GP fault which QEMU handles by noting that the code has modified itself, invalidating the translation, and so on. Plenty of details can be found in [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2016-01/msg02328.html) and elsewhere.

It's a reasonable mechanism, and I expect other code-translation VMs do something similar.

Note that in the case of self-modifying code, the "garbage collection" problem is simple: the emulator is informed about the SMC event as described above, and since it has to re-translate at this point, it throws away the old translation.

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks. So am I correct to interpret that "problematic instructions" here means practically *every instruction* that references memory at a non-fixed address (or which references the instruction or stack pointer, etc.)... (which is a massive fraction of binary code)? Also, do you happen to know how they deal with the issue of garbage collection case? Though I would assume they basically just translate every single `mov` into something that checks a refcount or something, but that seems awfully slow

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm not really sure what you mean by "non-fixed address"?

Comment: For self-modifying code, I think your mental model is that the result of the code translation is somewhat like the native code, with some patches and modifications. At least in the case of QEMU, that's not really the case - _every_ basic block is translated and as you can see the resulting code is quite different. To detect self-modifying code, my understanding is that the translated code lives in pages with R+X permissions, so a write raises a GP fault which QEMU handles and then notes that the code has modified itself. This lets the most code not pay a penalty for that.

Comment: Yeah, that's my mental image because VirtualBox says it patches "problematic" code, not "every" code :-) but otherwise that totally makes sense and is what I would expect from an emulator. Thanks a ton for the info! You should add that last bit about page permissions into your answer so it's a full answer! I'll be happy to accept it after.

Comment: Yes, perhaps VirtualBox leaves the code in a more natural state, but from looking at a few `-d asm_in,asm_out` runs of various constructs, it is clear that QEMU radically changes the native code to the point where it is hard to recognize it, at least by default on my machine. That said, it does seem like it still directly accesses memory at arbitrary addresses (e.g., when I wrote a loop like [this](https://gist.github.com/travisdowns/7ed6e1703aeeafa499b405190a47683b)), but it only does one iteration before doing the "thunk" thing.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I added an SMC section, and also a second about the stack _address_ changing.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I would note that although I don't know what VirtualBox does exactly, KVM also uses [TCG](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/TCG) when it can't rely on hardware virtualization features like VT-x and friends. So we can say this approach is reasonably widespread.